# Display 2 tables on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im new to codeigniter and php, need some enlightment to display 2 tables with mvc method. just displaying two tables in one page (camera and visitor table). here is my code

Model :

```
function m_report() {
        $camera = $this->db->get('camera');
        return $camera->result();
        $report = $this->db->get('visitor');
        return $report->result();
    }
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($data1 as $report){ ?>
               <tr>      
                  <td><?php echo $report->Country; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $report->Days; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php } ?>

<?php foreach($data_camera as $camera){ ?>
                   <tr>      
                      <td><?php echo $camera->cameratype; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
```

Controller :

```
function report(){
        $data['data_camera']=$this->m_data->m_report();
        $data1['data1']=$this->m_data->m_report();
        $this->load->view('v_report',$data,$data1);


}
```

the problem is, i can display camera table but visitor got error Message: Undefined variable: data1

Can anyone help me to figure it out? Much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return ONE thing from a method - once you return something, execution of code stops.

```
function m_report() {

    $camera = $this->db->get('camera')->result();
    $report = $this->db->get('visitor')->result();

    return array_merge($camera, $report);
}
```

Now you get an array with all the results from both "camera" and "visitor". You can specify it out if you'd like with an associative array.

```
function m_report() {

    $data['camera'] = $this->db->get('camera')->result();
    $data['visitor'] = $this->db->get('visitor')->result();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your help, I tried to change my model with your code, the problem is still the  same, the visitor table not appears, is there something wrong with my controllers maybe?

Comment: @anulogi Did you also change the way you parse and use that data in the view? If so, update to show your current code.

Comment: No I didnt change, Im sorry im new to CI.. Can you help how to parse the data in the view?

Comment: @anulogi Assuming you use example 2 out of those I sent, and you pass the variable as `$data` to the view, you should be able to access its contents by`$data['camera']['insert column name here']` - but then again, I don't use CI. Try var_dumping $data in the view and see what it contains, that should give you a good idea of how to use it.

Comment: Hi Marcus, somehow I figure it out, im using same view, just modified the models, create each model for 2 tables. and it works. anyway thanks for your respon!

Answer (score 0):

you can not make 2 returns in one method

```
function m_report() {
    $camera = $this->db->get('camera');
    return $camera->result();
    $report = $this->db->get('visitor');
    return $report->result();
}
```

i think it is better to make each query in single function

```
function m_camera_report() {
    $camera = $this->db->get('camera');
    return $camera->result();
}

function m_visitor_report() {
    $report = $this->db->get('visitor');
    return $report->result();
}
```

then call them separately in controller

```
function report(){
    $data['data_camera']=$this->m_data->m_camera_report();
    $data['data_visitor']=$this->m_data->m_visitor_report();
    $data1['data1']=$this->m_data->m_report();
    $this->load->view('v_report',$data,$data1);
```

}